# ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to get my user authenticated by using firebase authentication. But when the user clicks on the button and listener starts the authentication my activity stops and errors appear:

ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera

Complete errors image:

[image]

My Modle:app file is:

[image]

Please tell me as it's an essential part of my application and I have to use firebase at any cost. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: check if Play Services is present, up to date on your device.

Comment: Yes they are present and updated as well.

Comment: post your manifests

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.h.demo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".first_screen">

Comment: <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Log says Google Api not enabled in API console.

```
Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
```

so enable

Comment: Thank You, I have enabled Google+ API and all the other APIs are also enabled, now your diagnosed error is gone but the follwing errors are there:

Comment: ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera

Comment: E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `Androi 30` if you use the Emulator without Google Play API just add this line to `build.gradle`

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
```